# Plotting list as alist of functions

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions

I have a long list, every element of it depends only on a single variable.
How can I explain Wolfram that it is a list of functions to be plotted?

I beg my pardon if this is a simple question, but I could not find the answer and the problem is rather urgent.

---

Excuse me, I found that the problem with plotting was due to functions turning imaginary over a given segment.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please show a small example of an input, and explain what output (plot) you need. The question is not clear as written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Good news; you just need to plot your list.

Let's build a list of expressions that depend on t:

```
RandomSeed[24]; 
someList = 
 Table[Sum[
   RandomInteger[{-100, 
      100}] t^(RandomInteger[{-100, 100}]/
       RandomInteger[{1, 4}]), {RandomInteger[{0, 7}]}], {4}]
```

gives us:

> {0, -41 t^3, -37 t^(43/2), 68/t^(81/4) - 76 t^(4/3)}

Now we can simply plot them:

```
Plot[someList, {t, 1/2, 3/2}]
```

generates:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you're asking.  Here are two possible interpretations:

```
mylist[a_] := {.2 a^2, Sin[a], Cos[3 a + 1], a + .4 a^2 -.5};

ListPlot[mylist[.3], 
 PlotRange -> All,
 Joined -> True]
```

or

```
Plot[mylist[a], {a, 0, 4},
 PlotRange -> All]
```